# tcl - excel. change font of cell

Tags: excel, tcl

please help me find examples of working with the font of the text in the Excel cell in the TCL code. Turn on Border Bottom and use underline the text. Screenshot of the parameters I need to change below.
I found examples [enter link description here](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tcom+examples+for+Microsoft+Excel) but not exactly for underline the text

Thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: I imagine it involves getting a COM handle to the cell and calling the right method on it. I've no experience with almost all of what I've described so I can't provide more detail.

Comment: I found examples https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tcom +examples+for+Microsoft+Excel , but exactly for underline the text can`t find

Comment: # Define a range of cells to use with the following commands.
 set range [$worksheet Range B2 C3]  # Set some font properties for the cell range.
 set font [$range Font]
 $font Bold [expr 1]
 $font Italic [expr 1]
 $font Name "Courier"
 $font Size [expr 18]

 # Set some border properties for the cell range.
 set borders [$range Borders]
 $borders Weight $border(weight,thick) 
 $borders Item $border(line,bottom)

Comment: Pls update your question to contain the code snippet, properly formatted!